# Редирект с одной страницы на другую

Tags: wordpress, url

Такая ситуация:

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы содержимое страницы http://site/coupon-categories/for-children октрывалось по ссылке просто http://site/for-children, так как я в Wordpress не могу это изменить. А мне этот **coupon-categories** в урле не надо, тем более что у меня нет такой страницы http://site/coupon-categories
Можно ли так сделать и в каком файле что надо прописать?

Comment: либо используйте плагины, либо напишите правило в htaccess: `RewriteRule ^for-children$ /coupon-categories/for-children`

Comment: вот я вставил http://joxi.ru/Vm697v4Sx6w33r и не помогло. Может не там вставил?

Comment: после rewritebase

Comment: Не момогло. Всё равно /coupon-categories/ остался в ссылке

Comment: на то, что генерит wp это не повлияет, естественно. htaccess преобразует только входящие ссылки

Answer (score 1):

Чем вам не нравится стандартное решение? В админке WP идёте в настройки => постоянные ссылки, там в общих настройках выбираете пункт "Произвольно" и задаёте маску `/%postname%/`. Всё, никаких названий рубрик в url не будет

Comment: пробовал...название рубрики самой темы вордпресса всё равно остаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Я такое реализовал при помощи плагина "Remove Category URL". Попробуйте.

Comment: Валерий, я установил этот плагин только что и не вижу признаков этого плаина в админке, после того, как установил и активировал его. Где его настроить?